# AngularJS ui-router otherwise to state instead of url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and in my `app.js`. I have the following line:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

However **I do not want it to send the user to a URL** but *instead* **to a state**:

```
.state('404',
        {
            views: {
                'body': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
                }
            }
        });
```

Normally I would just do this:

```
$state.go('404');
```

How can I do this for the otherwise method?

*Note: that my 404 state does not have a URL, so basically it keeps the URL that the user has entered or visited and just changes the template.*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you achieved that with this code

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
  $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
    $state.go('404');
  }]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try This**.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    $injector.get('$state').go('404');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a small improvement to @kdlcruz's answer:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){
    $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
        $state.go('404', {}, { location: false } );
    }]);
});
```

By doing that, you still able to keep the incorrect the URL and only state is changed.