# Angular ui-router infinite loop when urlRouteProvider.otherwise is set

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-digest

I'm getting an infinite loop for this code:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var isLoggedIn = (authService.authentication && authService.authentication.isAuth);
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            //if user is logged and tries to access login page, prevent it
            if (toState.name === 'app.login') {
                event.preventDefault();
                return fromState;
            } 
        } else {
            if (toState.name !== 'app.login') {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('app.login');
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

I also have this set:

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');

    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
        template:'<div ui-view></div>'      
    })
    .state('app.login', {
        url: '/logn'
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/security/login.html'
    })
    .state('app.main', {
        url: '/main'
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/main.html'
    })
    ...
}
```

Now i'm getting infinite digest loop when user enters the site and must be authenticated.
It goes like this:

1. User enters the address ie: http://localhost
2. The default route (**otherwise**) fires and reddirects user to http://localhost/#/main
3. $*OnStateChangeStart* fires (for **app.main**) and test if user is logged in, if not then prevent default event end redirect to '**app.login**';
4. $*OnstateChangeStart* fires (for **app.login**) and test if toState.name is app.login' if so, then no need to redirect so return.
5. I don't know why but then $*OnStateChangeStart* fires again but for **app.main**.
   end it lops over and over.

Please help.

Comment: Hey, I experienced a similar issue not long ago and I had to change my declaration of the otherwise method to how it is in the answer to this SO post (let me know if it helps): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181141/angularjs-ui-router-otherwise-to-state-instead-of-url

Comment: It seems that this is the answer. Will test a little more and then accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the `otherwise()` method declaration to a state name transition instead of a URL transition which you are currently using. This solved it for me when I experienced this problem.

Heres an example:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
  $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
    $state.go('app.main');
  }]);
});
```

An alternate way of getting the `$state` and executing the `$state.go` would be

```
var $state = $injector.get('$state');
$state.go('app.main');
```

I'm not very experienced in Angular so I don't know why this solves it so if anybody can elaborate please do!

**Update**

The accepted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190180/angular-1-4-1-ui-router-10-digest-iterations-when-state-go-called-on-statec) seems to provide a good explanation on why this happens.

Comment: Sorry it hasn't helped, maybe some code elsewhere is causing this error for you. If you haven't found a solution I would suggest creating a new question including the relevant code so people can help you debug / fix it

Comment: Helped, Thanks a ton!